# hazelcast partition does not have an owner exception

Tags: hazelcast

I'm getting the following exception when I try to send a message to a hazelcast topic. Using a hazelcast client to a hazelcast node (hazelcast 3.6)

Any thoughts as to what this might be?  It's pretty much a basic out of the box server and client config I am using.

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientNotActiveException: Partition does not have owner. partitionId : 25
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveResponse(ClientInvocationFuture.java:146)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.get(ClientInvocationFuture.java:100)
    at com.hazelcast.client.util.ClientDelegatingFuture.get(ClientDelegatingFuture.java:118)
    at com.hazelcast.client.util.ClientDelegatingFuture.get(ClientDelegatingFuture.java:105)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientReliableTopicProxy.addWithBackoff(ClientReliableTopicProxy.java:128)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientReliableTopicProxy.publish(ClientReliableTopicProxy.java:102)
    ... 10 more

Caused by: com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientNotActiveException: Partition does not have owner. partitionId : 25
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.notifyException(ClientInvocation.java:180)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:137)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientRingbufferProxy.addAsync(ClientRingbufferProxy.java:163)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientReliableTopicProxy.addWithBackoff(ClientReliableTopicProxy.java:128)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientReliableTopicProxy.publish(ClientReliableTopicProxy.java:102)
    at com.rbccm.sabre.dataloader.infra.msg.hazelcast.HzTopicPublisher.publish(HzTopicPublisher.java:34)
    at com.rbccm.sabre.dataloader.infra.monitor.MonitorMessagePublisher.publishExpectedFiles(MonitorMessagePublisher.java:21)
    at com.rbccm.sabre.dataloader.infra.DefaultLoadSequence.execute(DefaultLoadSequence.java:41)
    at com.rbccm.sabre.dataloader.DataLoaderServiceImpl.load(DataLoaderServiceImpl.java:30)
    at com.rbccm.sabre.dataloader.controller.DataLoaderController.load(DataLoaderController.java:80)
    at com.rbccm.sabre.dataloader.controller.ControllerRequestConsumer.consume(ControllerRequestConsumer.java:51)
    at com.rbccm.processmanager.common.pubsub.ProcessEventQueueHandler$1.run(ProcessEventQueueHandler.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveResponse(ClientInvocationFuture.java:133)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: is this the very first error in the log? is there anything else suspicious?

Comment: @Jackson Ha could u resolve this Isssue ? if yes, how exactly ? I am getting the same Exception. HAzelcastClientNotActive

Comment: no. like sancar said....  basically disconnected from hz.   really not much you can do

Answer (score 5):

HazelcastClientNotActiveException suggests that client has shutdown when trying to get a partition table to send a topic message. You need to focus on why client decided to shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @sancar the real problem is the *HazelcastClientNotActiveException*, in my case I encountered the following exception on the server:

```
[com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionErrorHandler] (hz._hzInstance_1_prov0-group.cached.thread-4) [10.131.2.28]:5701 [prov0-group] [3.12.5] Removing connection to endpoint [10.129.17.173]:5701 Cause => java.net.SocketException {Connection refused to address /10.129.17.173:5701}, Error-Count: 5
```

Once i solved that the cache started to work correctly

Comment: how exactly did you solve this? im also getting same error, when I restart all instances and start the job again it computes fine but hz goes down abruptly while being used.

Comment: I don't remember since it was some time ago, but probably there was some network problem and the an instance wasn't reachable. You may want to look at memory usage as well.